# Vite apps build error from dockerfile, how build?

Tags: node.js, gitlab, dockerfile, vite

I have dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.20-alpine3.17 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV VITE_PATH_TO_SERVER "https://172.10.10.3:8003/"
COPY . .
RUN npm install \
    && npm run build
```

When run `docker build` i have next error:

> #13 13.71 [vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:1:1
> #13 13.71 file: /usr/src/app/src/_context/ContextGlobal.tsx
> #13 13.71 error during build:
> #13 13.71 Error: Parse error @:1:1
> #13 13.71     at parse$e (file:///usr/src/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:16018:355)
> #13 13.71     at Object.transform (file:///usr/src/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:45421:27)
> #13 13.71     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> #13 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

But, if I run `npm install && npm run build` local on computer without docker. All worked fine, without error.

In `/usr/src/app/src/_context/ContextGlobal.tsx` proger added only 2 lines, and after that, everything stopped working.

```
  console.log('import.meta.env.VITE_PATH_TO_SERVER', import.meta.env.VITE_PATH_TO_SERVER);
  console.log('import.meta.env.PATH_TO_SERVER', import.meta.env.PATH_TO_SERVER);
```

How i can build?

I try change FROM in dockerfile

Comment: I don't know what happened, but after second push in gitlab, pipiline worked out.

Comment: Hi, your solution is in a comment. This doesn't help others... Maybe no one will read it. Please put the solution in a regular answer, and read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) thank you